# How is netbeans corrupting my code on auto indent?

Tags: php, netbeans, centos

I have a phtml file.
It's working fine as it is. But once I hit `Alt+Shift+F` the code auto indents itself. 
But then, it's no longer getting rendered. An error is being displayed in the console.
"Network Error: 500 Internal Server Error"
I am running `Netbeans 8.0` on a `Centos` Release 6.4.

Comment: You might have a hidden charaacter in your code that isnt visisble, do a simple test with small code and check its length.

Comment: Can you guide me on this, please? @SidHussain

Comment: What's the error that you are getting on the console?

Comment: @Dave Network Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Hi Riju, what I mean was type something in the editor very short, and do the indent, then count the character you have typed, you cannot count a character you cant see, but if you use php, you can do sthign like this <?php $str ="copied from netbeans"; print strlen($str); ?> , if you get different count, then you know there is a hidden character.

Comment: @SidHussain Tell me exactly what to type.

Comment: Riju, i tried it my self, the Alt-Shif-F, does not cause any problems. I think, you might have another problem, does your server show php errors?

Comment: @SidHussain The Alt+Shift+F doesn't cause any errors, true. Even I have been using this very cool and useful feature of Netbeans since ages but then I was using Netbeans 7.3 and it's only today that I got 8.0 installed on my machine.
If it truly is another problem then how do you explain my code working fine once I undo the changes made by Alt+Shift+F (Just one Ctrl+Z)?